# looping through all TH and TD cells in a table

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#contentdiv table tr").each(function () {
$('td', this).each(function () {
var tdVal = ($(":first-child", this).is(":input"))
? $(":first-child", this).val()
: ($(this).text() != "")
? $(this).text()
: $(this).html();

.....JS code using all the values found in each TD cell.....
```

The above is working as it finds all the TD cells in all the tables in the div, but now I find that I need to include the TH cells as well.  Is there a nice way to do it using 1 `.each()` method?

I thought maybe I could do this, but that isn't working as expected.  I would like to know if it is a TH or TD tag as well.

```
$("#contentdiv table tr").each(function () {
var tdCell = ($(":first-child", this).is(":input"))
? $(":first-child", this).val()
: ($(this).text() != "")
? $(this).text()
: $(this).html();
```

I got results for only the 1st table.  There could be multiple tables in the `#contentdiv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, add your `th` as-well:

```
$('th, td', this).each(function () {
```

If you want to know where the value comes from:

```
$('th, td', this).each(function () {

    if (this.tagName === "TH") {
        // I'm a TH element
    } else {
        // I'm a TD element
    }

});
```

Comment: That makes it easy!  How can I tell if the value is coming from a TD or a TH?

Comment: He's mixing jQuery and pure javascript.  My preference is usually to use one or the other as code is easier to read not mixed (my opinion).  So the jQuery way is `var $this = $(this);  if ($this.is('th')) { ... }`.

Comment: thank you @ErikPhilips for your valuable comment. Luckily every browser *will* return an UpperCase tagName - unless someone tackled at some point with the `tagName` property (bad thing to do anyways) this should work fine :)